# How to check html helper check box by default in asp.net mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to check a html helper default in asp.net mvc3 but it is not happening.
Can anyone please help me regarding it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide some more information on what you are trying to do and what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You can set its checked property

```
@Html.CheckBox("myCheckBox", true)
```